# Mathjax renders blank text with angular html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I have been using mathjax for in one of my angular projects. Everything was working fine, until we decided to switch the html5 mode ON in our project to remove the `#` from URLs.

But on doing that the Mathjax rendering got affected. Portions of the string that had latex were rendered as blank, Also no javascript errors were thrown.

I can ensure that html5 mode is the only cause here, since disabling it again brings mathjax back to normal.

What could be conflicting here and any workarounds?

**Update:**

This problem occurs when Math-Rendering is set to SVG, when I switch to HTML-CSS it works again, but I need it in SVG mode itself